# Write to Datastore using HTTP API without committing transaction

Tags: transactions, google-cloud-datastore

### Context

I'm coming from a basic understanding of **SQL transactions** which flow something like:

1. `BEGIN` a SQL transaction. For argument's sake let's say we're using the [`Read Committed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Read_committed) isolation level.
2. Run an arbitrary number of `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements within the SQL transaction. None of which are visible outside
   the transaction (yet) due to the 'Read Committed' isolation level we're using in this hypothetical.
3. `COMMIT` the transaction, making the our `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s and `DElETE`s to others. Alternatively `ROLLBACK` the changes. Either way the transaction is no longer relevant.

Now I'm trying to use this understanding of SQL transactions to bootstrap my understanding of **Google Datastore transactions** and have hit a snag. The [Datastore REST API v1 documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/) does indeed have [beginTransaction](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/beginTransaction), [commit](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/commit) and [rollback](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/rollback) endpoints so at first blush it looks like a simple analogue of the SQL transaction system. However the Datastore [commit](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/commit) endpoint also functions as our (apparently only) mechanism for modifying data in Datastore. It is the fact that one endpoint appears to be responsible for two (in my mind) distinct yet vital operations that is causing confusion for me.

Possibilities (which I have explored):

- Perhaps there's something obvious in the [Datastore documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/) I have managed to overlook - *Well, it isn't obvious to me* ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
- Perhaps there's a phantom 'mutate' Datastore endpoint that isn't documented - *Unlikely, but I can hope*
- Perhaps there's a way to use the mutation functionality of the [commit](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/commit) endpoint without actually committing the transaction - *There is a [mode](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/commit#Mode) parameter for the commit endpoint with values of `TRANSACTIONAL` and `NON_TRANSACTIONAL` (which is described as "The mutations may not apply as all or none"). Perhaps the `NON_TRANSACTIONAL` option is simply poorly named/described and can be used to submit mutations within a transaction without immediately committing them (yet they will all be committed/rolled-back when the transaction is eventually committed/rolled-back). I am currently investigating this option*
- Perhaps Datastore doesn't support submitting mutations without committing them - *I'm really hoping this isn't the case*
- Perhaps Datastore transactions behave significantly differently to SQL transactions - *Quite possible*
- Perhaps my (above stated) understanding of SQL transactions is incorrect - *That would be super awkward*

### The Actual Question

If the Datastore [commit](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/commit) endpoint conflates the submission of mutations and the committing of those mutations, how can I submit modifications to the Datastore via the REST API without committing those modifications immediately?

Comment: Dear Jaysen, I am encountering the exact problem trying to implement Datastore transactions. Maybe since you've posted this question you've come to know more about this than me. Is it really impossible to create, update (or delete) transactionally without directly implying the end of the transaction by doing it within a commit? Have you found a way to perform multiple transactional creates, updates and deletes without committing?

Comment: @GlobalRationality From memory, I don't think I ever did find a neat way. I think I just had to architect around this aspect of the API

Answer (score 0):

**NON_TRANSACTIONAL** means that changes that you want to apply will be applied in undefined order, and results of such commit will be visible in undefined order through relatively undefined order. Too much undefined, I know. Shortly saying, they are behaving just like independent separate mutations.

**TRANSACTIONAL** means the same as in SQL world. In mutations body you would pass all mutations that you want to be done, and all of them will succeed or non of them. That is all the difference + concurrency control specified by ACID standard.

If you talking about some accumulative model of transactions, when you can begin such transaction, send some changes into datastore (accumulate it), and then apply such snapshot on datastore, then, it is not possible.

Documentation says, that:

> When mode is TRANSACTIONAL, mutations affecting a single entity are applied in order. The following sequences of mutations affecting a single entity are not permitted in a single projects.commit request:
>
> - insert followed by insert
> - update followed by insert
> - upsert followed by insert
> - delete followed by update

This line means

> mutations affecting a single entity are applied in order

That mutations accumulator is on your side.

Transactions in datastore is short living things.

> Transactions have a maximum duration of 60 seconds with a 10 second idle expiration time after 30 seconds.

Link to transaction descriptions in datastore.
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions